# Python loop to extract all sequences shorter than 100AA in multiple fasta files

Tags: loops, biopython, fasta

I'm kinda new to python and I wrote a script to loop through all fasta files in a directory and extract the sequences shorter than 100AA of each file:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import os

def loop_extractsmorfs(input_handle, output_handle):
    files = os.listdir(input_handle)

    for file in SeqIO.parse(files, "fasta"):
        if len(file.seq) <= 100 :
            files.append(file)


    SeqIO.write(files, output_handle, "fasta")

if __name__=="__main__" :
    loop_extractsmorfs(input_handle=sys.argv[1], output_handle=sys.argv[2])
```

When I run this code on the terminal using both the input_handle and output_handle as arguments I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I imagine there must be some mistake in the way I'm using the os.listdir or something but the examples I found online only show how to "print the files in that directory" and I need to extract and write new files.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `parse` a `list` of files. `SeqIO` cannot do this. You should parse each file separately & then, for your convenience, unite resulted iterators into one (via `chain` in my example). Necessary sequences should be stored in a seclude list.
So:

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import chain


def loop_extractsmorfs(input_dirpath: Path, output_filepath: Path) -> None:
    little_records = []
    for record in chain(
        *(SeqIO.parse(filepath, "fasta") for filepath in input_dirpath.iterdir())
    ):
        if len(record.seq) <= 100:
            little_records.append(record)

    SeqIO.write(little_records, output_filepath, "fasta")


if __name__=="__main__" :
    loop_extractsmorfs(
        input_dirpath=Path(sys.argv[1]), output_filepath=Path(sys.argv[2])
    )
```

This could be put into a list comprehension but I would not like to overload the answer.